# Redirect from https page to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a single page on my site that has a shopping cart function that allows credit card purchases. I want this page to be served with https. When users leave that page, I want them to be redirected back to http pages. When I set up the rewrite rules I can deliver the HTTPS page no problem, but when I add rules to send the user back to HTTP, the entire HTTPS page breaks because all the assets get redirected to http or something. Here is my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bookings.html 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bookings.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/bookings.html [R=301,L]
```

I am using absolute urls in my html. I would just serve the whole site HTTPS, but the client has tripadivsor widgets that are very important to his business and they break over HTTPS.

Comment: well, look at it this way: "if https is on AND the requested url is NOT bookings.html, then redirect to http".  so if you're on the booking page via https (no redirect there) and request an image, `kittens.jpg`, that url is NOT booking.html, so it'll redirect to non-https, breaking https page security. If you want to send then back to non-http, then make your "go back" links on the https have non-https urls, e.g. `<a href="http://example.com/done.html">`

Comment: yeah I was starting to put that together. Is there a way for htaccess to only target the address in the address bar?"

Comment: that's what the 301 is. do a client-side 301 round-trip redirect.

Comment: Ok, duh. I was under the impression that even links away had to be https, but its just the assets on that page. I added http to all the links going back or away and now every thing is fine.

Comment: nope. they don't have to be. some browsers might spit up a "you are leaving a secure page" warning, however. but then there'd be no way to transfer between secure and insecure anyways... any reason you don't want all your pages to be secure? everything's moving to "ssl everywhere" anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should skip `http(s)` redirections for images/css/js files. Try these rules:

```
#skip images/css/js
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/bookings\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^bookings\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on .htaccess file

```
<Location /bookings.html>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```